# How to produce/consume XML using swagger-node

Tags: json, xml, node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm new at using swagger-node (swagger-spec 2.0) and I have a need for my API to consume and produce both XML and JSON (because that's what the customer wants). Currently I have only focused on the "produce" part.

When producing a response, I know I can turn my js object into XML using tools such as [jstoxml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstoxml) or [easyxml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easyxml). So the question is: is this necessary when using swagger-node or are the tools suppose to handle this? I guess I need help in what my controller code should return.

For example, create a new project using swagger
`swagger project create myproject (choose express framework)`

Change the yaml file for the `/hello` api so that `get:` returns both json or xml

```
paths:
  /hello:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: hello_world
    get:
      description: Returns 'Hello' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: hello
      produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
```

Then change the hello_world.js controller to return a json object instead of a string

```
  // variables defined in the Swagger document can be referenced using req.swagger.params.{parameter_name}
  var name = req.swagger.params.name.value || 'stranger';
  var hello = util.format('Hello, %s!', name);

  // this sends back a JSON response which is a single string
  res.json({message:hello});
}
```

When I start the project and use Postman with Header Accept = application/json
I get the response:

```
{
    "message": "Hello, stranger!"
}
```

If I change the Header `Accept application/xml`, I still get the JSON response, not XML. What I was hoping to see is:

```
<object>
<message>Hello, stranger!</message>
</object>
```

I know my code is wrong to use `res.json()` because I believe it sets the Content-Type to `application/json`.

I don't know what else to use to produce the XML response. When I change out the res.json() to use easyxml

```
var xml = easyxml.render({message:hello});
res.type('xml').end(xml);
```

I then get a validation error from swagger:

```
[
  {
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Response validation failed: value expected to be an array/object but is not"
  }
]
```

So how should my controller be formatting the response to return either XML or JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what easyxml is doing or why it's not working, but `jstoxml` works great:

```
var jstoxml = require('jstoxml');
var express = require('express');
var util = require('util');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = 'stranger';
    var hello = {
        object: {
            message: util.format('Hello, %s!', name)
        }
    };
    if (req.headers.accept === 'application/xml') {
        res.type('xml')
        res.end(jstoxml.toXML(hello));
    } else {
        res.json(hello);
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8100);
```

**Accept: application/json**

```
{
    "object": 
    {
        "message": "Hello, stranger!"
    }
}
```

**Accept: application/xml**

```
<object>
    <message>Hello, stranger!</message>
</object>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is more than just getting express to respond with valid xml and am getting the same validation error from swagger as Greg (using js2xmlparser to generate the xml). I think it has something to do with the swagger.yaml or swagger.json file not defining the response schema correctly as it seems to be expecting an object or array instead of an xml string. In my swagger.yaml I have tried adding the following, but still no luck:
`produces:
  - application/json
  - application/xml`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is **no** correct way.
remus' answer does not take into account [Swagger explicit XML support](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#xml-object).
In any case the controller should definitely not mess with the API i/o formats, but just implement business logic.